# How can I check if a thread is inside a synchronized block or method?

Tags: java, concurrency

My Java application uses two Threads. Historically grown, there are synchronized methods and dedicated lock objects in use. I need to know wether the current thread has a lock and if it is by method or object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When entering a synchronized method the VM sets a lock on the current object. Thus the following codes have the same effect:

```
synchronized void syncMethod() {
    // do something
}

void syncManually() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

That means the synchronized method does exactly the same as

```
synchronized( lock ) {
    // do something
}
```

anywhere in your code.

You can use `Thread.holdsLock(...)` to check if the thread holds a specific lock. Here is an example code:

```
final Object lock = new Object(); 

public void lockDemo() {

    System.out.println( Thread.holdsLock(lock) );     // false
    System.out.println( Thread.holdsLock(this) );     // false

    synchronized ( lock ) { 
      System.out.println( Thread.holdsLock(lock) );   // true: locked by object
      System.out.println( Thread.holdsLock(this) );   // false
    }

    doSyncMethod();
}

public synchronized void doSyncMethod() {
    System.out.println( Thread.holdsLock(lock) );  // false
    System.out.println( Thread.holdsLock(this) );  // true: locked by synchronized method
}
```

Since Java 1.5 more sophisticated locks like [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) are supported by the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package.
They can provide separated read and write locking and improve the performance of your application. The [Lock Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) chapter of the Oracle Java Tutorials is a good start here.

Answer (score 1):

If you manually request a thread-dump the JVM will print out a stack-trace of each thread including what objects/methods are locked or waiting on a synchronized block.

You can manually request a thread-dump by sending the JVM process a SIGQUIT in *nix or by typing `CTRL-Break` (not `Ctrl-C`) in a Windows command-prompt window where the JVM was started.