# How to correctly use synchronized?

Tags: java, android, synchronized, synchronized-block

This piece of code:

```
synchronized (mList) {
    if (mList.size() != 0) {
        int s = mList.size() - 1;
        for (int i = s; i > 0; i -= OFFSET) {
            mList.get(i).doDraw(canv);
        }
        getHead().drawHead(canv);
    }
}
```

Randomly throws AIOOBEs. From what I've read, the synchronized should prevent that, so what am I doing wrong?

Edits:

AIOOBE = Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception
The code's incomplete, cut down to what is needed. But to make you happy, OFFSET is 4, and just imagine that there is a for-loop adding a bit of data at the beginning. And a second thread reading and / or modifying the list.

Edit 2:

I've noticed it happens when the list is being drawn and the current game ends. The draw-thread hasn't drawn all elements when the list is emptied. Is there a way of telling the game to wait with emtying the list untill it's empty?

Edit 3:

I've just noticed that I'm not sure if this is a multi-threading problem. Seems I only have 2 threads, one for calculating and drawing and one for user input.. Gonna have to look into this a bit more than I thought.

Comment: IOORE? Please expand to a full exception name - I dare say we could work out what you meant after a little while, but it would be a great deal simpler if you'd actually tell us to start with.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. Where is data *added* to the list (and, for that matter, removed)? What is `OFFSET`?

Comment: If it's `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you're talking about, I usually abbreviate that as aioobe ;-)

Comment: Only thing that I can see if doDraw(canv) removes more than one object from the same list then the next i would not exist if OFFSET = 1

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: are you sure you want `i > 0` and not `i >=0`?

Comment: @Lumis doDraw(canv) does not modify the list in any way (unless reading from it is modifying)

Comment: @toto2 Yes, as you see I call getHead().drawHead(canv) underneath. getHead() returns the first (0) element, and another method needs to be called on it.

Comment: I was just wondering about the same thing with i >= 0..

Comment: Maybe you also want to have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084793/how-can-i-check-if-a-thread-is-inside-a-synchronized-block-or-method/5084853#5084853), where I explained the different ways of synchronizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing *looks* right... but that's all:

1. It doesn't matter on what object you synchronize, it needn't be the list itself.
2. What does matter is if all threads always synchronize on the same object, when accessing a shared resource.
3. Any access to SWING (or another graphic library) must happen in the AWT-Thread.

To your edit:

> I've noticed it happens when the list is being drawn and the current game ends. The draw-thread hasn't drawn all elements when the list is emptied. Is there a way of telling the game to wait with emtying the list untill it's empty?

I think you mean "...wait with emptying the list until the drawing has completed." Just synchronize the code doing it on the same lock (i.e., the list itself in your case).

Again: *Any access to a shared resource must be protected somehow.* It seems like you're using `synchronized` just here and not where you're emptying the list.

Comment: Yes, point 2. is really important.  @SBoss we don't see the rest of the code where `mList` is also used, but __every__ code segment that  accesses or modifies `mList` must be protected by `synchronized(mList)`.  Synchronizing just one part of the code is completely useless.

Comment: 1. So I could just write synchronize()?
2. Thanks, didn't know that. I'll check my code.
3. AWT?

Comment: @SBoss No, if you have for example `synchronize(this)` around an `mList` in instances `MyClass class1` and `MyClass class2`, the `this` locks on two different locks and there would be no synchronization as far as `mList` is concerned.

Comment: @SBoss In answer to Edit2: you have to synchronize the block of code in your end game that empties the list!  You have to synchronize your code every time you use `mList`; you'll have other bugs otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The safe solution is to only allow one thread to create objects, add and remove them from a List after the game has started.

I had problems myself with random AIOOBEs erros and no synchornize could solve it properly plus it was slowing down the response of the user.

My solution, which is now stable and fast (never had an AIOOBEs since) is to make UI thread inform the game thread to create or manipulate an object by setting a flag and coordinates of the touch into the persistent variables.

Since the game thread loops about 60 times per second this proved to be sufficent to pick up the message from the UI thread and do something.

This is a very simple solution and it works great!

Comment: List is only created / modified / emptied from 1 thread. The UI thread only reads / draws the objects.

Comment: In my games, UI thread only informs the game thread what to do, nothing more. Since I have only one thread to do the logic I have a good control when and how things are done. I don't know if this would be appropriate for your application though, but it is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and I think you are looking for this solution also. How you can do it? It is already shown with an example in the javadoc :)

```
 class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   Object produce() { ... }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   void consume(Object x) { ... }
 }

 class Setup {
   void main() {
     BlockingQueue q = new SomeQueueImplementation();
     Producer p = new Producer(q);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(q);
     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
   }
 }
```

The beneficial things for you are, you need not to worry about synchronizing your `mList`. `BlockingQueue` offers 10 special method. You can check it in the doc. Few from javadoc:

> BlockingQueue methods come in four forms, with different ways of handling operations that cannot be satisfied immediately, but may be satisfied at some point in the future: one throws an exception, the second returns a special value (either null or false, depending on the operation), the third blocks the current thread indefinitely until the operation can succeed, and the fourth blocks for only a given maximum time limit before giving up.

To be in safe side: I am not experienced with android. So not certain whether all java packages are allowed in android. But at least it should be :-S, I wish.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting Index out of Bounds Exception because there are 2 threads that operate on the list and are doing it wrongly. 
You should have been synchronizing at another level, in such a way that no other thread can iterate through the list while other thread is modifying it! Only on thread at a time should 'work on' the list.

I guess you have the following situation:

//piece of code that adds some item in the list

```
synchronized(mList){
    mList.add(1, drawableElem);
    ...
}
```

and

//code that iterates you list(your code simplified)

```
synchronized (mList) {
    if (mList.size() != 0) {
        int s = mList.size() - 1;
        for (int i = s; i > 0; i -= OFFSET) {
            mList.get(i).doDraw(canv);
        }
        getHead().drawHead(canv);
    }
}
```

**Individually** the pieces of code look fine. They seam thread-safe. But 2 individual thread-safe pieces of code might not be thread safe at a higher level!
It's just you would have done the following:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
if(v.length() == 0){    v.length() itself is thread safe!
  v.add("elem");        v.add() itself is also thread safe individually!
}
```

**BUT the compound operation is NOT!**

Regards,
Tiberiu

Comment: I understand that the example with the Vector is not thread safe since you are not synchronizing on a check-then-modify operation, but the two blocks synchronized on mList are perfectly thread safe.

Comment: Yep.. You are right. I've just thought it over again and you're right. I've initially thought at check-then-modify issue but the access to the list is protected with the synch blocks. And as said here, if it's the same lock that is being used, then all should be fine. Cheers, Tiberiu