# How to Junit test a synchronized object not accessed by two threads at same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, hashmap, synchronized

Is there any way I can make a Junit test to make sure that a synchronized object (in my case HashMap in synchronized block) is not accessed by two threads simultaneously? e.g. forcing two threads to try to access and having exception thrown.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: isn't that like testing a JVM functionality? if so, its already well tested.. else, you can create a runnable which will loop for a long time and try to access the method you are trying to test. run two instances of this thread to see if there is any collision. If the locking objects are same this wont happen inside synch block. so i feel its like testing JVM which is not needed.

Comment: I am requested for an implementation of a cache which provides - single instance of the cache, type safety and thread safety and Test for each of these features. i am using hash map to model the cache and singleton design pattern for single instance and generic to provide type safety. and when testing the code, i don't have anyway to test the thread safety feature and looking for some means to come around this. Thanks!

Comment: for caching purposes,  use `ConcurrentHashMap`, if you are allowed to.. then you don't have to worry about thread safety.

Comment: Is there any way to provide unit test for thread safety then? I implement methods put and get for the cache and i am delegating to the corresponding map methods. I t would be possible to make the test if exception will be thrown when another thread try to access the cache while another has the lock to it.

Comment: thread safety is built inside `ConcurrentHashMap`, its a guarantee from the Class. There no reason for you to doubt that, unless you feel that there is a bug in the class implementation or java library.. same goes with the synch block scenario..

Answer (score 1):

The best framework I've seento help with thread testing is [Thread Weaver](https://github.com/google/thread-weaver). At the very least it offers some deterministic way of thread scheduling, and a limited (yet useful) way of trying to find race conditions.

You can even code up some more intricate thread scheduling scenarios, but those tests will inevitably be white box tests. Still, those can have their use too.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can make a Junit test to make sure that a synchronized object (in my case HashMap in synchronized block) is not accessed by two threads simultaneously?

I'm not sure there is a testing framework to test this but you can certainly write some code that tries to access the protected `HashMap` over and over with many threads.  Unfortunately this is very hard to do reliably since, as @Bohemian mentions, there is no way to be sure how threads run and access the map, especially in concert.

> e.g. forcing two threads to try to access and having exception thrown. Thanks for your help!

Yeah this won't happen for 2 reasons.  As mentioned, there is no "forcing" of threads.  You just don't have that level of control.  Also, threads do not throw exceptions because of synchronization problems unless you are doing something other than `synchronized(hashMap) { ... }`.  When a thread is holding the lock on the map, other threads will block until it releases the lock.  This is hard to detect and control.  If you add code to do the detection and thread control then you get into a Heisenberg situation where you will be affecting the thread behavior because of your monitoring code.

Testing proper synchronization is very difficult and often impossible to do.  Reviewing code with other developers to make sure that your `HashMap` is fully synchronized *every* time it is used, maybe be more productive.

Lastly, if you are worried about the `HashMap` then you maybe should consider to moving to `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap)`. These take care of the synchronization and protection of the actual map for you although they *don't* handle race conditions if you are making multiple map calls with one operation.  Btw, `HashTable` is considered and old class and should not be used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation! I know it is difficult and that is why i asked over here in case there is a way that i am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have a code similar to this one

```
synchronized(myHashMap) {
    ...
}
```

... which means that a thread acquires the lock provided by `myHashMap` when it enters synchronized block and all other threads that try to enter the same block have to wait, i.e. [no other thread can acquire the same lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

> Is there any way I can make a Junit test to make sure that a synchronized object (in my case HashMap in synchronized block) is not accessed by two threads simultaneously?

Knowing the above, why would you do that? If you still want to try then you might want to take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084793/how-can-i-check-if-a-thread-is-inside-a-synchronized-block-or-method).

<s>And last, but not least. I'd recommend you to use `Hashtable` because it's [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)</s>. Use [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: I am requested for an implementation of a cache which provides - single instance of the cache, type safety and thread safety and Test for each of these features. i am using hash map to model the cache and singleton design pattern for single instance and generic to provide type safety. and when testing the code, i don't have anyway to test the thread safety feature and looking for some means to come around this. Thanks!

Comment: `HashTable` is considered a dead class and should not be used.  `ConcurrentHashMap` is the modern replacement for it.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you can't, because you can't control when threads are scheduled, let alone coordinate them to test a particular behaviour.

Secondly, not all build servers are multi threaded (I got bitten by this only a couple of days ago - cheap AWS instances have only 1 CPU), so you can't rely on even having more than know thread available to test with.

Try to refactor your code so the locking part is separated from your application and test that logic in isolation... if you can.